# Flask, WTForms: Error when edit and create form rules are differents

Tags: python, flask, rules, wtforms

I'm using Flask and WTForms in a web app. I have a db.Model, a form and a sqla.ModelView like this:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

class UsersForm(form.Form):
    id = fields.IntegerField('Id')
    name = fields.StringField('Name')
    last_name = fields.StringField('Last Name')

class UsersAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ['id', 'name', 'last_name']
    form = UsersForm
    form_create_rules = column_list
    form_edit_rules = ['name', 'last_name']
```

But it doesn't work because this error:

```
ValueError: Form <__main__.UsersForm object at 0x7f5039c48710> does not have field name
```

However, when form_edit_rules is equal to form_create rules, it works perfectly!

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your issue, but shouldn't the column list be a tuple instead of a list? See https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/

Comment: I've changed lists for tuples, but the error is still there :(

Comment: Is there a github of this app I can close to test myself?

Comment: I just created one: https://github.com/brivadeneira/testing-form-rules

Answer (score 0):

I found out on flask-admin github issuelist that form_*_rules only affect how form is displayed, but don't affect the form itself.

Creating an instance of a form in flask-admin is not necessary. I would recommend to have your database take care of the id, as it automatically auto-increments. In my experience, flask-admin doesn't even show the id field.

If you really want to have an editable id field on the create form only, you can make the field readonly on the edit form with the following code:

```
class UsersAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
        form.id.render_kw = {'readonly': True}

    column_list = ['id','name','last_name']
    form = UsersForm
```

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation, but the id is only for testing, in the project I'm working create and edit forms don't include the id.

Comment: Well, in that case, remember that you cannot hide fields with form rules. The error message on the name field I cannot reproduce, that part worked fine here. I did get errors on the missing id field on the form edit rule in your original code though.